# Относительное местоимение, которое относится ко всем однородным членам

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые, однородные-члены

**Есть ли в тексте пояснения, вставки, излишние детали, добавления, которые отвлекают?**

Как показать, что слово *которое* относится ко всем однородным членам, а только не к последнему?

Answer (score 1):

**Есть ли в тексте пояснения, вставки, излишние детали, добавления, которые отвлекают?**

Показывать грамматически ничего не надо, так как каждый из членов этого однородного ряда **требует определения.**

Например, рассмотрим отдельно часть ряда без придаточного определительного: *Есть ли в тексте пояснения, вставки?*  Как очевидно, вопрос не имеет смысла: пояснения и вставки или есть, или их нет.

Поэтому  придаточное **однозначно относится ко всем членам ряда**.

Comment: 1) Я не пойму, почему вы и пользователь "Мимоходов" считаете, что каждый член однородного ряда требует дополнения и что иначе вопрос не имеет смысла? "Если ли в тексте пояснения [какие-либо], вставки [какие-либо], излишние детали [какие-либо], ну и добавления, которые отвлекают? 2) А кстати, если бы было необходимо ограничиться последним членом или двумя последними? "Есть ли в тексте пояснения, вставки, а также излишние детали и добавления, которые отвлекают?" — так было бы?

Comment: Вы для этого предложения коммуникативную ситуацию обозначьте, тогда и на вопросы можно будет отвечать.  Я поняла, что речь идет о необходимости редактировать текст, убрав из него всё лишнее,  то есть всё то , что   обозначено однородным рядом, а "лишнее" для этого ряда  как бы обобщающее слово. Если Вы о чем-то другом говорите, значит, говорить надо яснее.

Comment: Вы правильно всё понимаете.

Comment: Есть ли в тексте отвлекающая от основного содержания информация: пояснения, вставки, излишние детали, добавления? Это вариант с обобщающим словом. А у вас роль обобщающего слова играет общее определительное придаточное. которое относится ко всему ряду.

Comment: Понял. Не могли бы ответить на второй вопрос в первом комментарии про то, как можно было бы ограничить отнесённость придаточного?

Comment: В этом варианте придаточное будет относиться только к двум последним членам ряда, но это же не так.

Comment: Я просто спросил на будущее, что делать, если возникнет такая необходимость.

Answer (score 0):

В обычном тексте ничего показывать не надо, это понимание по умолчанию. Проблема бы возникла, если бы требовалось "ограничить" действие "которого" последним членом.
Здесь, кстати, просто невозможно подобным образом интерпретировать даже по смыслу: упоминание пояснений и вставок вообще было бы непонятным и бессмысленным, если бы на них не распространялось действие "которые отвлекают".

В юридически значимых текстах, правда, используют специальные формулировки, исключающие всякую двусмысленность, но там само слово "которые" крайне редко используется. Сильно сомневаюсь, что ваша фраза для юридических казуистов писана, но в подобном случая она выглядела бы примерно так:

***Прошу сообщить, имеются ли ли в тексте отвлекающие (от основного смысла?) особенности: пояснения, вставки, излишние детали, добавления.***

Answer (score 0):

> Есть ли в тексте пояснения, вставки, излишние детали, добавления, которые отвлекают.

С точки зрения понятности, текст требует только добавления вопросительного знака (если это отдельное предложение). Но звучит он несколько коряво по двум причинам: (1) слишком короткое придаточное; (2) глагол "отвлекают" желательно  дополнить информацией о том, кого и от чего отвлекают.

**Есть ли в тексте пояснения, вставки, излишние детали, добавления, которые отвлекают читателя (от основной мысли)?**

Comment: Вопросительный знак не поставлен по недосмотру — исправил. Вы тоже согласны, что придаточное здесь отчётливо относится ко всем однородным членам?

Comment: Да, с этим я согласен.

Comment: А если бы было необходимо ограничиться последним членом? "Есть ли в тексте пояснения, вставки, излишние детали, а также добавления, которые отвлекают от основного смысла?" — можно так?"

Answer (score 0):

Есть ли в тексте элементы - пояснения, вставки, излишние детали, добавления, - которые отвлекают?